# Universal Link. Unmatchable character

Tags: ios, hyperlink, universal

I am having problems trying to match **'#'** character for Universal Link file (apple-app-site-association).

For an URL like *domain/#/results/parameters* I've been trying with:

- /?/results/*
- /*/results/*
- /#/results/*
- /\#/results/*
- /%23/results/*

But none of them worked for me.

The annoying point is the two first matches the almost equal URL *domain/a/results/parameters* (whatever character instead #)

How can I match the #?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "#" character is typically used in web URLs to specify a page fragment. As the documentation states, fragments are ignored when evaluating a path for Universal Links:

> "Other components, such as the query string or fragment identifier,
>   are ignored."
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

Comment: This link is not updated by Apple from 2016. Can you post updated reference link please?

Comment: Universal links now support fragments. Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/56753530/2513947

Answer (score 3):

@salazar, Finally Apple has heard our queries. Now you can specify fragments in the form of components from iOS 13

The apple-app-site-association structure is changed like this,

```
 "applinks": {
   "details": [
     {
    "appIDs": [ "TeamID.com.example.myapp"],
    "components": [
          {
            "/": "/path/#mypath/*",
            "#": "*fragment"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You can find more information about universal linking here - https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717/

Note - The documentation is not updated yet at the time of writing this answer.

Comment: Check this WWDC video: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/717/

Comment: i have watched this, thanks to you. I am looking for help. I want to support "https://domainhere/#coupon?action=srtu" type of url for universal links. I want to add fragment for "#coupon" in AASA file. Can you help me? How to add this part.....

Comment: If there is "#coupon" in the url, it should open my app.... I could really use your help here..@Rizwan Ahmed. Note that it is after domain.... 

example: https://gddg.com/#coupon?action=srtu

Comment: {
 "applinks": {
   "details": [
     {
    "appIDs": ["{YOUR_TEAM_ID.BUNDLE_ID}"],
    "components": [
          {
            "/": "/*",
            "#": "coupon*"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: So magic part is "{
                        "/": "/*",
                        "#": "company"
                    }"  right?

It will open the link. it it working in "AND" condition basis. I mean it will check for path and the fragment both for this particular piece of code...???

Comment: Yes it should. Give it a try

Comment: Thanks Bro. I will give it a try and let you know...... Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hii @Rizwan Ahmed Above solution not working for me

Comment: Can you try like this?

{ "applinks": { "details": [ { "appIDs": ["{YOUR_TEAM_ID.BUNDLE_ID}"], "components": [ { "/": "*", "#": "coupon*" } ] } ] } }

Comment: I was trying this before. was not working for me either...I am clueless.

Comment: This was looking more promising <"{ "/": "/*", "#": "company" }">... but no luck

Comment: Have you specified your appID properly? Enabled the universal linking option in signing and capabilities?

Comment: Yes. Universal links working fine for other alerts. Just not this one with #.

Comment: Do you think it wil work with this <"#": "/*company"> ?? Can you test this out

Comment: Show me your json structure and give me a sample URL.

Comment: I made a slight change and its working fine now. "{ "/": "/*", "#": "coupon*" }">

Comment: Good. Happy to help.

Comment: If I have the query param like ?path=ScreenGroup:my-fleet{"selectedIndex":1} -- how should I escape the double quotes?